# Unable to resolve module ./app.json in RN version 0.70

Tags: metro-bundler

I was Working in RN 0.69.2 version. Yesterday I have upgrade it to RN 0.70 version.
I followed the guideline in React native helper. But I got error in Metor, it's says unable to resolve module './app.json'. when I tried to npm start --reset-cache I got other error which says
References Error sha-1 .

I tried all solutions in stackoverflow but the Error wasn't solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm having the same issue, able to resolve it by adding `json` at the end of `metro.config.js` file under resolvers like this

```
resolver: {
 sourceExts: ['jsx', 'js', 'ts', 'tsx', 'json'], //add here
}
```