# React Native (Android) - Failed to transform hermes-debug.aar

Tags: android, react-native, upgrade

I am working on an old React Native app and want to upgrade RN version from version ^0.64.2 to 0.70.1. After using command `npx react-native upgrade`, there are changes in number version of dependencies. I also edit `build.gradle` in `andriod\app` folder as instructed in this [document](https://reactnative.dev/docs/hermes):

```
project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: true  // clean and rebuild if changing
]
...
dependencies {
    ...
    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
    ...
}
```

After that, I run command `./gradlew clean` in android folder and run `npx react-native run-android`. Then this error shows up:

```
BUILD FAILED in 9s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform hermes-debug.aar to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: D:\{ProjectFolder}\node_modules\hermes-engine\android\hermes-debug.aar.
         > Transform's input file does not exist: D:\{ProjectFolder}\node_modules\hermes-engine\android\hermes-debug.aar. (See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158753935)
```

After taking a while, I also found out that there is no `hermes-engine` folder inside `node_modules` folder but still have no clue what to do.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@notifee/react-native": "^3.0.4",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.10",
    "@react-native-community/art": "^1.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.5.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.9.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^12.9.0",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.2.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.1",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "fbjs": "^3.0.4",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.34",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.1",
    "react-native-biometrics": "^2.1.4",
    "react-native-camera": "^3.35.0",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^6.12.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^2.0.4",
    "react-native-file-viewer": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.32.2",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.6",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^5.4.24",
    "react-native-pdf": "^6.2.0",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.0",
    "react-native-pie-chart": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.0.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.13.1",
    "react-native-simple-toast": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^3.2.9",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.0.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.0",
    "react-query": "^3.34.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "toggle-switch-react-native": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-root-import": "^6.5.0",
    "eslint": "^7.14.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

**Update**: The error still occur after I edited package.json and use `npm install` to add `hermes-engine`. Here are the errors:

```
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-query@3.34.2
npm ERR! Found: react@18.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"18.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from @jsamr/react-native-li@2.3.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@jsamr/react-native-li
npm ERR!     @jsamr/react-native-li@"^2.3.0" from react-native-render-html@6.3.4
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-native-render-html
npm ERR!       react-native-render-html@"^6.3.4" from the root project
npm ERR!   27 more (@react-native-community/art, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from react-query@3.34.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-query
npm ERR!   react-query@"^3.34.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from react-query@3.34.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-query
npm ERR!     react-query@"^3.34.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Comment: Try to run the command with --force

Comment: Thank you for your advice. But I solved this problem by removing every dependencies except for react and react-native, then upgrade to version 0.70.1 and reinstall the dependencies. I also found that some of them are already deprecated and changed to other repositories. I use depcheck to help checking for unused and missing dependencies.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm also upgrading RN version to 0.70.1, from 0.69.x you have some changes to do in `app/build.gradle` about hermes.

```
...

if (enableHermes) {
    implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-engine:+") {
        exclude group: 'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }
} else {
    implementation jscFlavor
}
```

- ```
    def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
  ```
- ```
    debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
  ```
- ```
    releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermesrelease.aar")
  ```

  ...

Source: [Bundled Hermes Documentation](https://reactnative.dev/architecture/bundled-hermes)

Answer (score 5):

Try to add this to your package.json and npm install again with --legacy-peer-deps option:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "hermes-engine": "^0.11.0",
  },
```

Comment: It doesn't work and get the errors while installing hermes-engine. I have updated the question by adding log for the errors.

Comment: Also refer this if you have errors with hermes https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33120

Comment: @Anandeva Thank you for posting this thread. After I upgraded and reinstall the dependencies, I encounter the same error. This thread provide me the answer and the app is now successfully built. However, I still encounter error like in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73624232/unable-to-resolve-module-app-json-in-rn-version-0-70)

Answer (score 1):

I went through the same error and followed the solution suggested by @fernando-garcía, but to my case it was not enough.
Indeed, I was getting the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'isBatchingLegacy' of undefined, js engine: hermes
```

The problem is definitely due to **hermes**, but I had to tune some other things to properly update my react-native application and let it work with `react-native` 0.70.0.

Here the steps I had to do to properly update my React-Native application in order to solve the problem:

1. Add the following snippets in `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    if (enableHermes) {
        //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-engine:+") {
            exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
        }
    }
}

if (isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
    // If new architecture is enabled, we let you build RN from source
    // Otherwise we fallback to a prebuilt .aar bundled in the NPM package.
    // This will be applied to all the imported transtitive dependency.
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
            substitute(module("com.facebook.react:react-native"))
                    .using(project(":ReactAndroid"))
                    .because("On New Architecture we're building React Native from source")
            substitute(module("com.facebook.react:hermes-engine"))
                    .using(project(":ReactAndroid:hermes-engine"))
                    .because("On New Architecture we're building Hermes from source")
        }
    }
}
```

2. add the following inside `android/settings.gradle`:

```
if (settings.hasProperty("newArchEnabled") && settings.newArchEnabled == "true") {
    include(":ReactAndroid")
    project(":ReactAndroid").projectDir = file('../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid')
    include(":ReactAndroid:hermes-engine")
    project(":ReactAndroid:hermes-engine").projectDir = file('../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/hermes-engine')
}
```

3. update the `react` dependency inside your package.json (I had `17.0.2` and I had to update to `18.1.10`):

```
dependencies {
    ...
    "react": "18.1.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also interested about this issue, the same thing is happening for me, I already checked the Upgrade Helper, and I am upgrading from 0.68.5 to 0.70.1.

I still haven't turned on the NEW_ARCHITECTURE flag.

Installing hermes-engine package seems like not a good solution, since the upgrade steps doesn't mention that it should be done.